# I'm designing a preamp to connect 10K load. I need 2vptp at output from an 200mVptp input. but I want these bias conditions

Tags: gain

Need gain 0f 10. without changing dc bias conditions. what will be best solution?

[image]

Comment: This design seems somewhat overenginered. T2 alone has enough input resistance, gain and drive to amplify by ten the microphone onto 10k load. If the output load were  given some extra allowance one might just consider a two stage circuit, but in this case an overall feedback would really be the right choice.

Comment: Leon - Hi, I have "rolled-back" (i.e. reversed) your change to the question. That change is too big, and it makes the existing comment & answer obsolete. I'm not sure what you intended to achieve with that edit - if you want to ask a totally new question, then please do so [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your current circuit the base of T1 is at 75/(75+15)* 9 = 7.5 V.
The emitter of T2 will be at about the same level, 7.5 V.
T2's bias emitter current (and roughly its collector current) will therefore be (9-7.5)/(530+22) = 2.7 mA. So in the current configuration its collector voltage is about 2.7*1.8 = 4.86 V. Its emitter voltage is 9-(0.530+0.022)*2.7 = 7.5 V.

If you want a gain of 10 you'd have to make R5' = 10 * R8 = 5.3k.
But then its collector voltage would become 2.7*5.3 = 14.3 V which is not possible with a 9 V supply.

You'll get 1 V range (2 Vpp) if the collector of T2 is just 1 V, I guess we can take 2 V. Then the emitter is at 9 - 0.2 (- 0.05 for the decoupled resistor) = 8.75 V. So we'll have to change R1, R2 accordingly, say, R1 = 2.5k, R2 = 87.5k.

For the same bias current in T2 we need R8 = 0.25V/2.7mA = 92.5 and R4 = 23.
Then R5 = 10 * 92.5 = 925 and the T3 collector is at 2.7*0.925 = 2.5 V.

This will probably work.

Comment: Your current R4 * C5 = 23 * 10u = 230 us or 1/4 ms, which correspondents with a f = 2.5 kHz which is a bit high. To make this, say, 10 Hz you'll have to increase C5 by a factor 250 to 25 mF. That's insane, did I get this wrong?